# Forcing RecyclerView to display all images as the same size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using the RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager to develop a gallery . I want the portrait and landscape images to display as the same size in the grid .How can I do this?

Comment: I have tried setting margins and using setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP). I also tried a method that someone had written. They all just lead to the image beside the portrait image to become distorted.

Comment: you have to post your code what you tried what was the result and what you want?

Comment: If you want them to be proportional, I.e. not stretched, then you'll probably have to crop the images using some logic and create new bitmaps. There are numerous posts about cropping images in Android programmically - just search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me .

```
   if (image.getWidth() >= image.getHeight()){
  image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, image.getWidth() / 2 - image.getHeight() / 2, 0,
      200,200);}
else
{image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, image.getHeight() / 2 - image.getWidth() / 2,
    200, 200);}
```

Answer (score 0):

What problem you are facing .Just add fixed size to your imageview .

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
     />
```